# How to get a extended SubClass from Google Gin using GinFactoryModuleBuilder?

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection, guice, gwt-gin

The GinFactoryModuleBuilder class comment says the following:

> In difference to regular Guice Assisted Inject, in Gin, return types
>   in your factory are not further resolved using your regular injector
>   configuration. This means that in the following example you'll still
>   get a Chicken and not a Rooster:
>
> ```
> interface Animal {}
>  public class Chicken implements Animal {}
>  public class Rooster extends Chicken {}
>  interface AnimalFactory {
>    Animal getAnimal();
>  }
>  ...
>  protected void configure() {
>    bind(Chicken.class).to(Rooster.class);
>    install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder()
>        .implement(Animal.class, Chicken.class)
>        .build(AnimalFactory.class));
>  }
> ```

Is there a way to get the Rooster class in gin? What about:

```
install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder()
        .implement(Animal.class, Rooster.class)
        .build(AnimalFactory.class));
```

And in my code:

```
@Inject
AnimalFactory f;
Animal rooster = f.getAnimal();
```

How do I create the Rooster?

**How to get a extended SubClass from Google Gin using GinFactoryModuleBuilder?**

Comment: Do you really want cascaded resolution of bindings or just wish to return Rooster from the factory? See my answer below for the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove everything from the configure method and keep only the following :

```
install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder()
  .implement(Animal.class, Rooster.class)
  .build(AnimalFactory.class));
```

and then use the factory as you did to get instance of Rooster from the factory.

Or, you can change your factory method to return Rooster & change configure as follows, and use the factory as you did :-

```
interface AnimalFactory {
   Rooster getAnimal();
 }
 ...
 protected void configure() {
   install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder().build(AnimalFactory.class));
 }
```